# Find String 2017 from a given string="Date-01-2017"

Tags: java, string

I have the code:

```
String str="Date-01-2017"
```

How can I print 2017 only from this string?

I don't know how to split and get the return as 2017.

Comment: Split by dash (`-`) and then get the third element of the array, like this: `str.split("-")[2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
String[] splitString = dateString.split("-");
String year = splitString[2];
```

Comment: or `String year = splitString[splitString.Length - 1];` for the last split just in case you have Date-01-01-2017.

Comment: Thanks to all for wonderful .responses

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring` method to take the part of the string you need:

```
String data = "Date-01-2017";
String year = data.substring(data.length() - 4, data.length());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the simplest way that you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **regular expression**:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+-(?<month>\\d{2})-(?<year>\\d{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Date-01-2017");

if(matcher.matches())
    System.out.println(matcher.group("year"));
else
    System.out.println("NOT MATCH!!!");
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/7eHWnB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to print if the string "2017" is using a function, such as this.

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
        return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
    }
```

You can make a call to this function, with the string as the parameter, and if the string contains 2017, then u can print out that string.

Comment: I think OP wanted to print the string "2017", not *if* the string contains it or not.